# WP7 SDK on Windows 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8

Is it possible to install WP7 SDK on Windows 8 Release Preview? I tried using [standard installation package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233) but keep getting following error:

> Installation Requirements:
>
> KB2669191 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your
>   computer.  Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225649
>   for more details.

I installed WP7 SDK 7.1 but had some compatibily errors durring the instaa. Right now I can start VS2010 for WP7 but cannot build the solution because of following error:

> The target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryContentProjectItems" does not
>   exist in the project.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out.  I am in the same boat.  Day two at work trying to figure it out :(

Comment: I gave up and reinstall Windows 7 :/

Comment: I wish that was an option...uggg...I have to do this though so ill let you know when I figure it out

Comment: It is September 9.. have we found any solution ?

Answer (score 5):

The following link gives the exact steps you need to perform in order to install and run WP7 sdk on windows 8 : [WP7 Sdk on Windows 8](http://blog.saraf.me/2012/09/install-windows-phone-7-sdk-on-windows-8.html)

Comment: There are many articles about this topic. This one is the most accurate.

Answer (score 2):

For development of XNA/WP7 on Win8: 
Install Windows 8, then Visual Studio 2012, then Windows Phone 8 SDK, ensure windows updates are installed (as Nov 2012 had some great App Store updates).  Then, port your XNA code across and create a new project to get the DLL references you need. The DLLs will exist in the Silverlight 4 folders but not to worry, it all works once you have WP8 SDK !!  The emulator runs great too!  This is the process for XNA code into VS2012 that works.

You can get the SDK from here:
https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

NOTE: The XNA games will ONLY work on WP7 devices.  You need MonoGame or similar to port to Win8 devices.

Answer (score 1):

You should install WPSDK 7.1 first, before installing 7.1.1 Update. Check the [Instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233#instructions) at the bottom of the page.

see [Installing Windows Phone SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245453).

Update:

I have used the SDK's 7.1 and 7.1.1 from the above link and they are working fine in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Windows Phone **7.1 RC SDK**, then install **7.1 RTW SDK**, and then the 7.1.1 SDK.
And every thing will be alright
[this link for 7.1 RTW](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570)

[and this for 7.1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233)

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This article finally did the trick.  Hopefully posting it here will save someone from the nigh terrors ive been experiencing lol.  The work around involves installing the xbox live marketplace and then installing the wp7 sdk and XNA will install normally.

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/03/05/windows-8-and-the-windows-phone-sdk.aspx

this will get the warning error to go away.  To fix the emulator problem you mus download the windows phone sdk 7.1.1 which is an update to the 7.1 sdk you were having problems installing

Answer (score 0):

The error 'GetCopyToOutputDirectoryContentProjectItems' has been known to come from Silverlight, therefore I recommend you try to reinstall the Silverlight SDK on your machine.

Source: [GetCopyToOutputDirectoryContentProjectItems](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/0a6f3cdd-df5b-4b75-b58d-d51f995892db)

Answer (score 0):

Please go ahead and install windows 8 RTM now, after you install RTM ,Install Visual Studio 2012 and then WIndows Phone 8 SDK.now with this SDK , YOU CAN WORK ON WP7 
as well as WP8

Answer (score 0):

you can install sdk update 7.1.1 if you didn't.. It solved the problem for me

[Download Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=29233&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True)

Answer (score 0):

This article solve my problem:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx

Basically was necessary install: Games for Windows – LIVE Redistributable from http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient, after everthing works :)