# Can't create project on Visual Studio for Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, windows-phone-7, sdk

I want to start developing App for Windows Phone. 
I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Express, Updating it to SP1. Install Windows Phone SDK 7.1. And when I want to create a new Project, here comes the error.

I have installed .NET Framework 3.5 to 4.5. Silverlight SDK 4.0. What am I missing here ?

I am using Windows 8 32 bit if it has any difference.

[image: The Error]

Comment: First, open your 'References' folder in project and check, if there's no warning sings there.

Comment: all of the reference have warning signs. What to do? I can't even create a new project :(

Comment: Wow. That's a bit strange. Lemme think... What's the 'target windows-phone OS version' in project properties? I don't know, if windows 8 works well with VS2010 + wp7, try to check which wp OS the project is using. (maybe it's trying to use wp8 OS?)

Comment: Tried Both WP7 and WP7.1. No WP 8. I didnt Install WP8 SDK

Comment: And WP8 Needs Windows 8 64bit which I dont have at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft made developing for windows-phone as complicated as possible. )

So, basically there are two solutions, that are guaranteed to work:

1) You can develop on Visual Studio 2010 for windows-phone-7 on Windows 7.

2)You can develop on Visual Studio 2012 for windows-phone-8 on Windows 8(64-bit).

The other variations are more like a 'dance with tambourine', in my humble opinion.

There are solutions, but they are all tricky.

---

What may work for you:

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073289/wp7-sdk-on-windows-8), maybe it helps.

The first answer has a [link](http://blog.saraf.me/2012/09/install-windows-phone-7-sdk-on-windows-8.html) with instruction of how-to install a sdk for wp7 on windows 8. Try it. However, there's no mention about 32-it system, so it might also not work.

Right now, you've said, you've installed SDK 7.0. Try to to, as suggested in above-mentioned link and install Windows Phone SDK 7.1 and 7.1.1 update.

Comment: Actually What I have installed is the SDK 7.1, not 7.0. Anyway I will install the rest of them which is not installed yet